# mpicc and matrix

Tags: c, mpi

I have a code

```
distance = (double**)malloc(city_count*sizeof(double*));
for(i=0; i<city_count; i++) 
{
distance[i] = (double*)malloc(city_count*sizeof(double));
}

for(i=0; i<city_count; i++)
{
  for(j=0; j<city_count; j++) 
      {
         distance[i][j] = 1; // fscanf(fp, "%d", &tmp); distance[i][j] = tmp; EDITED

  }
}
```

Then I debug it in Visual Studio it works just fine. But on a real cluster it always filled with zeros. Can anybody help me?

Problem with assignment to matrix, not in reading files.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `tmp` and the return value of 'fscanf' when running on the real cluster? The only other thing I can thing of, are you sure `city_count` isn't 0?

Comment: yes. It was exactly the same as I expected.

Comment: Problem with assignment to matrix, not in reading files. In other places there I AM NOT READING FILES the same thing.

Comment: I use mpicc for compiling. May be it's a C's feature???

Comment: See my updated answer. %d maps to an int*. You probably should be using %lf format.

Comment: I'm almost out of possibilities. One more question: What's the type of `distance`?.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be of any help. When you figure it out, please post the answer because now you've got me curious. (Two more thoughts: 1) if you spot check the value (with printf?) immediately after assignment, still 0's? (that would be weird). 2) Have you checked all the pointer values returned from malloc?) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But on a real cluster it always filled with zeros.

```
for(i=0; i<city_count; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<city_count; j++) 
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &tmp);
```

### Update

With your simplified problem statement (thanks for that) it pretty much leaves checking the pointer values returned by malloc to make sure they're not NULL (which would be *very* surprising unless city_count is really large.)

### Old Update

Doh! I just noticed. %d reads an int which doesn't match the type of &tmp. Should be:

```
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", &tmp);
```

`fscanf` isn't typesafe so this type of mismatch usually causes a problem.

#### Post Facto Edit

And make sure you're not making the same mistake passing "%d" to `printf`. ;-)

### End Update

Make sure `city_count` isn't `0`.

Check `fscanf`'s return value (and the value of tmp). Are you sure this file read is succeeding? [From the docs at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

Comment: I can use printf even on the real cluster.

Comment: Nope. One more time problem is not in fscanf. If I type distance[0][0] = 2.0 result would be the same.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep hammering on these other things. The real problem is, your code looks correct to me. I've written much code like this. (Though usually with a multi-dimensional array rather then the array of pointers to arrays that you probably require for some reason not shown.)

Comment: I figured it out. Your perseverance helped) Problem was not in scanf, but in printf. I used "%d" with double. It played a cruel joke on me. Thank you.

Comment: I did point out exactly the %d / double mismatch and that %ld was required. Is my answer acceptable?